# Cannot Upload Multiple Files to AWS S3 using Python Script and wildcards

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, boto3

I am newer to working with python as well as AWS.

I am attempting to move various files "and usually" with specific formats from my local pc to an S3 AWS folder via a python script. I am having an issue with implementing a wildcard within the script to catch various files at once. I am able to move one file at a time using the string "data = open('file_example_here.csv', 'rb')" , though I am stuck on adjusting my python script to capture all (i.e.  .csv or all .json files). An example set of files are detailed below, so if I wanted to move all .json files to my s3 instance using a wildcard in the script how could I go about adjusting my script to handle that ask if possible?.

Any help would really be appreciated , implementation is shared below.

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````
/home/user/folder1/c_log_1-10-19.csv
/home/user/folder1/c_log_2-10-19.csv
/home/user/folder1/c_log_3-10-19.csv
/home/user/folder1/c_log_4-10-19.csv
/home/user/folder1/c_log_5-10-19.csv
/home/user/folder1/c_log_6-10-19.csv

/home/user/folder1/h_log_1-11-18.json
/home/user/folder1/h_log_2-11-18.json
/home/user/folder1/h_log_3-11-18.json
/home/user/folder1/h_log_4-11-18.json
/home/user/folder1/h_log_5-11-18.json
/home/user/folder1/h_log_6-11-18.json

import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'key_id_here'
ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = 'secret_key_here'
BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket_name_here'

data = open('test_file.csv', 'rb')

s3 = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
)
s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object(Key='folder_test/folder_test_2/test_file.csv', Body=data)

print ("All_Done")


````````````````````````````````````````````````````
################################################
############## UPDATED CODE BELOW ############
################################################
import glob
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'some_key'
ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = 'some_key'
BUCKET_NAME = 'some_bucket'

#session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
s3 = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
)

csv_files = glob.glob("/home/user/Desktop/*.csv")
#json_files = glob.glob("/home/user/folder1/h_log_*.json")

for filename in csv_files:
    print("Putting %s" % filename)
    s3.upload_file(filename, BUCKET_NAME, filename)

#for filename in json_files:
#    print("Putting %s" % filename)
#    s3.upload_file(filename, BUCKET_NAME, filename)

s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object(Key='folder1/folder1', Body=csv_files)

print("All_Done")
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something as simple as Python's [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module to find all files matching a specified pattern as in this example below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob
import boto3
import os

BUCKET_NAME = 'MyBucket'
FOLDER_NAME = 'folder1/folder1'

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
s3 = session.client('s3')

csv_files = glob.glob("/home/user/folder1/c_log_*.csv")
json_files = glob.glob("/home/user/folder1/h_log_*.json")

for filename in csv_files:
    key = "%s/%s" % (FOLDER_NAME, os.path.basename(filename))
    print("Putting %s as %s" % (filename,key))
    s3.upload_file(filename, BUCKET_NAME, key)

for filename in json_files:
    key = "%s/%s" % (FOLDER_NAME, os.path.basename(filename))
    print("Putting %s as %s" % (filename,key))
    s3.upload_file(filename, BUCKET_NAME, key)

print("All_Done")
```

The above code assumes you have AWS CLI installed with an access key configured under the default profile.  If not, you can use the various methods of [authenticating with boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html).

There's probably a more pythonic way to do this but this simple script works.

Comment: Thank you for the response, and I updated the code above below the original. Though is there a way to structure the code to still maintain a string that puts the code in a particular folder on the s3 (.i.e. s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object(Key='folder1/folder1', Body=csv_files). Also, I was getting an error on the string ( s3.upload_file(filename, BUCKET_NAME, filename )  >> which stated (attributeerror: 's3.serviceresource' object has no attribute 'upload_file) ?? Have you can acrross that before @Ashaman Kingpin ?

Comment: @bobparker, Yes, the third argument to the upload_file call is the object key name that can contain the folder name.  Do you want to extract just the file name (e.g. c_log_1-10-19.csv) and put in a particular folder (folder1/folder1)?  If so, I've modified the code above to do so.

Comment: @bobparker, as for the error you are getting, note that in my code, I'm using boto3.Session while you are using boto3.resource.  That is likely the cause of the error.  Can you use the Session instead or do you have to use the resource for a particular reason?

Comment: @bobparker Looks like using the resource API is better than the client API.  I'll translate the code to use resource over client later this evening if you prefer.  Let me  know if this is unnecessary.

Comment: Hey thanks again, I am now able to get the .csv files to pass to the s3 instance, though I am now having an issue with getting them into a particular folder in the bucket.
   
 This works >>>> s3.upload_file(filename, BUCKET_NAME, filename)      This does not s3.upload_file(filename, BUCKET_NAME, 'folder1/')  @ Ashaman Kingpin

Comment: Weird, but I actually got it to work using the s3 = boto3.client >> instead of resource @Ashaman Kingpin

Comment: @bobparker Great, please don't forget to accept my response as the answer.

Comment: Ok will do, but do you know any reason why the files cannot get placed into a specific sub-folder in my s3. I am able to only able to send straight to the main s3 directory. This works >>>> `s3.upload_file(filename, BUCKET_NAME, filename)` This does not >>>`s3.upload_file(filename, BUCKET_NAME, 'folder1/')`
@Ashaman Kingpin

Comment: Ok, I got it :) lol >>>>>>   `s3.upload_file(filename, BUCKET_NAME, 'folder1' + '/' + filename)`   @Ashaman Kingpin

Answer (score 1):

Check out the glob module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

```
import glob
csv_files = glob.glob('/home/user/folder_1/*.csv')
json_files = glob.glob('/home/user/folder_1/*.json')
```

Then iterate over these lists and upload as you were doing.

Also, there's no need to read in the data from the file. Just use the *upload_file* method on the bucket: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.upload_file